# cant download curl or make on asus zenbook 14x - ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, asus, make, curl

I just dual booted my windows setup with the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Everything seems fine, but i can't seem to download basic terminal commands like for example 'curl' or 'make'.
when i use:

```
sudo apt install curl
```

I get the error message:

```
Package curl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'curl' has no installation candidate
```

i have tried following the fixes on the internet but to no help. any suggestions?